# How to calculate the amount of each ingredient?

Tags: php, nested-sets

I'm trying to solve a problem, where I need to calculate nutrition values of a recipe like a "My  sandwich"

I have a database with "recipes" and "ingredients" and the amount needed in kg.

a recipe can contain ingredients but also other recipes which then again can contain recipes/ingredients.

This is an example of a "part list" of a "Test Sandwich" with a total weight of 0.095 kg.

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'Test Cheese',
    'metric_id' => 1,
    'category_id' => NULL,
    'quantity' => 0.015,
    'depth' => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 3,
    'name' => 'Test Ham',
    'metric_id' => 1,
    'category_id' => NULL,
    'quantity' => 0.03,
    'depth' => 1,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 4,
    'name' => 'Test Sesam Bread',
    'metric_id' => 1,
    'category_id' => NULL,
    'quantity' => 0.05,   // Only use some of the test bread (with added Sesam)
    'depth' => 1,
    'parts' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 5,
        'name' => 'Test Bread',
        'metric_id' => 1,
        'category_id' => NULL,
        'quantity' => 1.0,         // This a recipe for 1 kg of banana bread 
        'depth' => 2,
        'parts' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'id' => 6,
            'name' => 'Test Flour',
            'metric_id' => 1,
            'category_id' => NULL,
            'quantity' => 0.5,
            'depth' => 3,
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'id' => 7,
            'name' => 'Test Water',
            'metric_id' => 1,
            'category_id' => NULL,
            'quantity' => 0.3,
            'depth' => 3,
          ),
          2 => 
          array (
            'id' => 8,
            'name' => 'Test Yeast',
            'metric_id' => 1,
            'category_id' => NULL,
            'quantity' => 0.05,
            'depth' => 3,
          ),
          3 => 
          array (
            'id' => 9,
            'name' => 'Test Banan',
            'metric_id' => 1,
            'category_id' => NULL,
            'quantity' => 0.15,
            'depth' => 3,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'id' => 10,
        'name' => 'Test Sesam Seeds',
        'metric_id' => 1,
        'category_id' => NULL,
        'quantity' => 0.1,
        'depth' => 2,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

How can I reduce such a structure to a list of amount/weight of each  individual "end" ingredients, like flour, water, bananas, cheese, ham, sesam seeds etc. ?

I written this function to run through the structure, but it's not really doing the job (seems like it calculate the total weight correctly)

```
function resolveAssembly($items, $number = 1, $declaration = [])
{
    $weight = 0;

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        // Get the quantity (weight) of the item
        $amount = $item['quantity'];

        // Check if the item also contains an ingredients list
        if (array_key_exists('parts', $item)) {

            // Get the total weight of the whole assembly
            list($assembly_weight, $assembly_declaration) = resolveAssembly($item['parts'], $number * $amount, $declaration);

            $declaration = array_merge($declaration, $assembly_declaration);

            // Calculate the relative weight of each part in the assembly
            foreach ($item['parts'] as $part) {
                $weight = $weight + ($amount / $assembly_weight) * $part['quantity'];
            }
        } else {
            // Add the amount to the declaration
            if (!array_key_exists($item['name'], $declaration)) {
                $declaration[$item['name']] =  $number * $amount;
            }

            $weight = $weight + $amount;
        }
    }

    return [$weight, $declaration];
}
```

Edit: merging assembly declaration array

This is how I use the above function:

```
$item = Inventory::findOrFail(1); // Get "Test sandwich"
$parts = $item->getAssemblyItemsList(); // Get the parts of the "Test sandwich"
$result = resolveAssembly($parts, 1); // Get total weight of 1 "Test sandwich" + a list of amount/weight of each ingredient
```

Current outcome of the resolveAssembly() function:

```
0.095
[
  "Test Cheese" => 0.015
  "Test Ham" => 0.03
  "Test Flour" => 0.025
  "Test Water" => 0.015
  "Test Yeast" => 0.0025
  "Test Banan" => 0.0075
  "Test Sesam Seeds" => 0.005 // Should have been factored in the bread ingredients
]
```

But it's not quite right, it should add up to 0.095, so the Test Sesam Seeds isn't factored in the stuff the bread is made up of (flour, yeast, banana etc.) I think.

0.015+0.03+0.025+0.015+0.0025+0.0075+0.005 = 0.1 kg of "Test Sandwich"

Also if this helps, I'm using this system to store these recipes: https://github.com/stevebauman/inventory/blob/v1.7/docs/ASSEMBLIES.md (but modified to store decimal numbers and also negative numbers (e.g. to handle water lost or added doing a cooking process))

And here is all the calculations done to sum the total weight of the "Test Sandwich":

```
"Test Cheese: 0 + 0.015 = 0.015"

"Test Ham: 0.015 + 0.03 = 0.045"

"Test Flour: 0 + 0.5 = 0.5"

"Test Water: 0.5 + 0.3 = 0.8"

"Test Yeast: 0.8 + 0.05 = 0.85"

"Test Banan: 0.85 + 0.15 = 1"

"Test Flour: 0 + (1 / 1) * 0.5 = 0.5"

"Test Water: 0.5 + (1 / 1) * 0.3 = 0.8"

"Test Yeast: 0.8 + (1 / 1) * 0.05 = 0.85"

"Test Banan: 0.85 + (1 / 1) * 0.15 = 1"

"Test Sesam Seeds: 1 + 0.1 = 1.1"

"Test Bread: 0.045 + (0.05 / 1.1) * 1 = 0.09045454545"

"Test Sesam Seeds: 0.090454545454545 + (0.05 / 1.1) * 0.1 = 0.095"
```

Comment: Show us that you have at least tried to solve this yourself by showing us the code you currently have

Comment: It would be much easier for everyone if that array was printer with `var_export` instead

Comment: RiggsFolly - you are right, I forgot to include my function - it seems to calculate the total weight correctly.
Andreas - fixed (thank you pointing it out)

Comment: 'Test Sesam Bread' is made up of 'Test Bread' and 'Test Sesam Seeds', should all three of these (and any sub parts) be listed in the ingredients list? Since only part of 'Test Sesam Bread' is used, does that need to be factored into it's sub parts?

Comment: @inckie if you could post how you expect the outcome to look that would be helpful

Comment: @khartnett - added the outcome, but values are not correct tho, but I need the amount of each "end" ingredient used to make up one "Test Sandwich" recipe.

So I need the amount of cheese ham, flour, water, seeds etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you closer:

```
function resolveAssembly($items) {
    $weight = 0;
    $declaration = [];
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $weight += $item['quantity'];
        if (array_key_exists('parts', $item)) {
            // if there are parts, get the full weight and declaration for the sub item
            list($sub_total_weight, $sub_declaration) = resolveAssembly($item['parts']);
            foreach ($sub_declaration as $sub_name => $sub_weight) {
                if (!array_key_exists($sub_name, $declaration)) {
                    $declaration[$sub_name] = 0;
                }
                // Total weight of particular ingredient is the sub items ingredient out of the sub items full weight
                // times the quantity for this particular item
                $declaration[$sub_name] += $item['quantity'] * ($sub_weight / $sub_total_weight);
            }
        } else {
            // if there are no parts, just add the quantity
            if (!array_key_exists($item['name'], $declaration)) {
                $declaration[$item['name']] = 0;
            }
            $declaration[$item['name']] += $item['quantity'];
        }
    }
    return [$weight, $declaration];
}
```

This will give you this result:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
  float(0.095)
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
        ["Test Cheese"]=>
    float(0.015)
    ["Test Ham"]=>
    float(0.03)
    ["Test Flour"]=>
    float(0.022727272727273)
    ["Test Water"]=>
    float(0.013636363636364)
    ["Test Yeast"]=>
    float(0.0022727272727273)
    ["Test Banan"]=>
    float(0.0068181818181818)
    ["Test Sesam Seeds"]=>
    float(0.0045454545454545)
  }
}
```

If you add up the numbers above, they should total 0.095.

Basically when you're doing a 'sub recipe' you need to know what the total 'weight' of that recipe is, and from there you can figure out the actual items total based on that sub's quantity.

Comment: Where should they add this? What does it do? Provide some context for your answer.

Comment: Is it correct to merge it ? Because as you said what if an ingredient in the assembly declaration already exists in the declaration, then it has to be added (I guess)

Comment: It seems there's a mix of what 'quantity' and 'weight' are. For example, it calls for 0.05 of 'Test Sesam Bread', however the two parts of 'Test Sesam Bread' sum up to 1.1"kg"

Comment: Yes and no.

I think of it as this way:

You don't bake a single loaf of bread, you bake a complete bread of 1 kg and add 0.1 kg (100g) of sesam seed to the bread, to create another variant of the bread.

Then you cut a loaf of that bread that has a weight of 0.05 kg (50g) to make your sandwich.

Comment: Thank you so much - I validated the function against real recipe data and it returns the same result as the old ~25 year old delphi program that is currently used to do these calculations.

Comment: Great to hear! My method was to start simpler with a recipe with only ingredients by doing `$result = resolveAssembly($parts[2]['parts'][0]['parts']);`. Once that worked I added parts and moved up a level to `$result = resolveAssembly($parts[2]['parts']);` and verified results. After that it just worked.

Comment: Your help was really useful, but now I need it do another thing. Care to take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56909578/flattern-a-tree-and-keeping-track-of-the-path-to-each-leaf ?